# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

i am trying to add a datepicker to a form in magento. when i click on the calendar image  i am getting the error in the console -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

i am getting this error in calendar.js  on first line of this code :

```
for (i = 0; i < Calendar._MN.length; i++) {
        a = a.replace(Calendar._MN[i], enUS.m.wide[i]);
    }
```

Here is the code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css') ?>" /> 
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('calendar/calendar.js')?>" ></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('calendar/calendar-setup.js')?>" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function(){
//<![CDATA[
    Calendar.setup({
    inputField : '_dob',
    ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
    button : '_dob_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    singleClick : true
    });
//]]>

});

</script>


<dl class="last">
            <dt><label><?php echo $this->__('Date of birth') ?></label></dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="input-box">
                <input style="width:40%;" name="dob[]" id="_dob" type="text"  class="input-text" />
                <img title="Select date" id="_dob_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif');?>" class="v-middle">
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
```

Thanks

Comment: So Calendar._MN is undefined, not much more to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the `calendar/lang/calendar-en.js` or your `calendar/lang/calendar-XX.js` where XX is your lang.
it seems that there no `Calendar._MN` array there; it must be an array like this :

```
Calendar._MN = new  
Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `Form.phtml` file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_calendar')->setTemplate('page/js/calendar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```